# Approach to load the json from the local path in to the html that would support in all browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Iam trying to load json data from the local path to a simple html page. I tried many ways to load the data using fetch, ajax.  i need to read the value from json and update the same in the html page .

I need to host this page and this would be used by people with their own browsers.

## Json_Development_Test.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('All assets are loaded')
  })
let request = new Request("./test.json")

fetch(request)
.then(function(resp){
    return resp.json();
})
.then(function(data){

   for(var i in data){
    console.log(i+data[i])
    document.getElementById(i).style.background = data[i]
}
})
```

## HTML

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.tableLayout {
  display:table;
}
.tableLayout > div{
  display:table-row;
}
.tableLayout > div > div {
  display:table-cell;
  border:solid;
  text-align: center;
}
    .Table
    {
        display: table;
    }
    .Title
    {
        display: table-caption;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    .Heading
    {
        display: table-row;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
        display:grid;
    }
    .fixed {
        table-layout: fixed;
        display:grid
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 26px;
        padding-right: 26px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Cell2
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 56px;
        padding-right: 34px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .Cell3
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 56px;
        padding-right: 35px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<body>
<header>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
    <h1> JSon Example </h1>

<script src ="Json_Development_Test.js">
</script>
</header>    

<div class="Heading">

    <div Class="Cell">
        <p>Project Name</p>
    </div>
    <div Class="Cell">
        <p>Service URL</p>
    </div>
    <div id="test">
        <span id="headerID1" class="Cell">
            <p>PDC</p>
        </span>
        <span id="headerID2" class="cell">
            <p>DDC</p>
        </span>
       <span id ="Time" class="Cell">   
            <P> Updated Checked Time</P>                
         </span>

    </div>  

</div>


    <div class="Heading">
        <div Class="Cell">
            <p>GRapd</p>
        </div>
        <div Class="Cell">
            <p>abc.com</p>
        </div>
        <div id ="Test">
            <span id="Pdata1" class="Cell2">
                <p>cp</p>
            </span>

            <span id="Ddata1" class="Cell2">
                <p>de</p>
            </span>


           <span id ="tdata1" class="Cell2">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
             </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="Heading">
        <div Class="Cell">
            <p>LEPRD</p>
        </div>
        <div Class="Cell">
            <p>bcd.com</p>
        </div>
        <div id="test">
            <span id="pdata2" class="Cell2">
                <p>HTP</p>
            </span>
            <span id="ddata2" class="Cell2">
                <p>HcP</p>
            </span>
           <span id ="tdata2" class="Cell2">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>


</html>
```

The above both works in some browsers as expected, but not in all browsers.

Expected:
The data from the josn should load in all browsers. I would like to know which should be the simple and best approach to load json from the local file path.

Actual:
The above java script not loading data in all browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the `fetch` api is not yet supported in all browsers namely Internet explorer so you have to use the XMLHttpRequest api or you can use the jquery ajax call api as jquery will handle the cross browser issues.